# "routerlink" only work for once then stop

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, rxjs, routerlink

I am building a angular 4 project, I have an parent component A, inside the HTML, there is a [routerlinkA], which link to component B. Inside component B, there are another [routerlinkB] link back to A. Everything works very well at first.
Later when I add and changed some code, I can successfully go from A to B through [routerlinkA], and also back from B to A through [routerlinkB], but when I tried to go from A to B again, this [routerlinkA] doesn't work any more! 
Because I have so many code and subscription(rxjs), for each subscription I added error catch, but there is no error throwing out to the console, so I am not sure where is the problem. 
I checked the HTML of the [routerlinkA], it seems like when I go back from component B to component A, that angular "ng router binding" is gone.

Also, I don't know if this is related to my error, from component A to component B, for the router path, if there is an params inside the path, it will lead to some div hidden in component B,but for the [routerlinkA] inside A, there is no params.

I am sorry because I could not put my code out for some reason.

Can anymore give any suggestions about which error could cause this situation? (It is hard for me to debug because there is no error in console)

Comment: Have you add / to all your router path in view

Answer (score 0):

check first that you have  added the component selector properly in components. eg:-`<app-componentA></app-componentA>` because having multiple selectors router-outlet neglects the first.